# Working with two entity managers in the same bundle in Symfony2

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony, entity, bundle

I'm trying to work with two entity managers for the same bundle. My configuration is like this:

```
orm:

    default_entity_manager:   default
    entity_managers:
        electra:
            connection:       electra
            mappings:
                XXDemoBundle: ~
        default:
            connection:       default
            mappings:
                XXDemoBundle: ~
```

Is there any way to tell which entities belong to which entity manager? It crashes now if I want to work with a table which doesn't belong to the default entity manager.

- UPDATE

here is my configuration for the connection:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:       default
        connections:
            default:
                dbname:           old_project
                user:             root
                password:         123123
                host:             1.1.1.1
                port:             1
            electra:
                dbname:           electra
                user:             root
                password:         123123
                host:             2.2.2.2
                port:             2

orm:
    default_entity_manager:   electra
    entity_managers:
        electra:
            connection:       electra
            mappings:
                XXDemoBundle: ~


        default:
            connection:       default
            mappings:
                XXDemoBundle: ~
```

Comment: Please post a simple example of what is crashing.  Both of your connections point to the same database?  Seems like you should also have auto_generate_proxy_classes in there and maybe auto_mapping but maybe not.  Try "php app/console doctrine:mapping:info --em" with first one then the other entity manager.

Comment: Hi! I use two different databases with two different connections. The mapping:info says I have no entities handled by the default entity manager, all my entities are handled by electra.

Comment: That means you have a config issue somewhere.  Please post your connection mappings.  doctrine:mapping:info should return the same list of entities for both ems.  Make sure you have the auto_generate line and that you are working in development mode.

Comment: Be aware that all your entities will be available to both managers.  Since they point to different databases there won't be any actual overlap i.e. you won't be able to join across the databases.

Comment: I'm not sure how to change a tag but you will probably get more views (and perhaps help) if this was tagged with doctrine-2

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For using multiple entitymanager in same bundle you have to config mapping options for each entitymanager.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Exemple off config file

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
            second:
                driver:   %database_sqlite_driver%
                host:     ~
                port:     ~
                dbname:   %database_sqlite_shop_name%
                path:     %database_sqlite_shop_name%
                user:     ~
                password: ~
                charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        default_entity_manager:   default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection:       default
                mappings:
                    YourBundle:
                      # you must specify the type
                      type:     "annotation"    
                      # The directory for entity (relative to bundle path)
                      dir:      "Entity/FirstDb"        
                      #the prefix 
                      prefix:   "Your\Bundle\Entity\FirstDb" 
            shop:
                connection:       second
                mappings:
                    YourBundle:
                      type: "annotation"
                      #here the second path where entity for the connection stand
                      dir: "Entity/SecondDb" 
                      #the prefix
                      prefix: "Your\Bundle\Entity\SecondDb"
```

You can now use console for managing your db with the --em parameter

Ex : update database for shop entitymanager

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --em=shop
```

Read mapping information from Your\Bundle\Entity\SecondDb

Ex : update database for default entitymanager

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update
```

Read mapping information from Your\Bundle\Entity\FirstDb

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the late comment.

Comment: Since this is an accepted answer, please pay attention that in newer version of Symfony you have to escape the backslashes in prefix like this: "Your\\Bundle\\Entity\\SecondDb", otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: Specified non-existing directory "Entity/FirstDb" as Doctrine mapping source.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Tried to edit your original post but it's waiting for peer review.  Not sure how long that takes.  Try changing your config to:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:       default
        connections:

        default:
            dbname:           old_project
            user:             root
            password:         123123
            host:             1.1.1.1
            port:             1

        # Make an explicit connection just for clarity
        old_project:
            dbname:           old_project
            user:             root
            password:         123123
            host:             1.1.1.1
            port:             1            

        electra:
            dbname:           electra
            user:             root
            password:         123123
            host:             2.2.2.2
            port:             2

    orm:
        # Humor me and add these
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    #   auto_mapping: true

    default_entity_manager:   electra
    entity_managers:

    # Make an explicit old_project em so default does not confuse us
    old_project:
        connection:       old_project
        mappings:
            XXDemoBundle: ~

    electra:
        connection:       electra
        mappings:
            XXDemoBundle: ~


    default:
        connection:       default
        mappings:
            XXDemoBundle: ~
```

Now completely blow away your cache just to be sure then run:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:info --em electra
php app/console doctrine:mapping:info --em old_project
```

You should get identical results.  I tested this on my system so I'm fairly certain that if you don't then you have some typo somewhere.

So mapping info is working.  Next step is to verify that both databases match your entity schema.  So do this:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --em electra --dump-sql
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --em old_project --dump-sql
```

Neither should produce any output.  If one does then it means your database does not match your entities and that needs to be resolved (possibly using the --force option) before queries will work.

Once the databases are in sync then you should probably use doctrine:query:dql and do a test query against both managers.  Then go back into your code.

=========================================

It has now been understood that the real goal is to have two entity managers point to the same set of entities but somehow indicate that each entity manager should limit itself to a certain set of those entities.  And that is not something the S2 supports out of the box.

You could look through the Doctrine manual and see how it handles the entity metadata and maybe do something with that but that could get complicated.

The only thing that S2 really offers is the ability to bind an entity manager to all the entities in one or more bundles using the mapping attribute.  If you wanted to share say three of seven  entities from one bundle with another bundle then you would simply recreate those entities in the second bundle.  Possibly by extending the class so as to avoid code duplication.

I think you might want to alter your approach a bit.  If you have a set of core entities shared with multiple bundles then put those in their own bundle.  Each follow on bundle can then add additional entities.

Comment: Updated my answer with new config to try

Comment: Now, the mapping seems fine, I see the same entities for the two entity managers. However, I get the same error wherever I try to access something in electra, it says:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.country_code' in 'field list'
500 Internal Server Error - PDOException

the country table is in the electra db, not with the one with the default connection

Comment: Updated answer based on that fact that both managers see the same entities.

Comment: Okay but the problem is I don't want to have all the same tables in the two databases, I just want to use some entities with the default, and the rest with the other. I don't want them to be synced in any way. I just simply don't understand how to tell doctrine which entity belongs to which database.

Comment: Revised my answer.  Bottom line is that S2 doesn't support your requirement out of the box.

Comment: My goal is to have one bundle, but with two entity managers, each of them is using a different database, I don't want to share the entities, for example in database A there's a table "country", in database B there's a table "car". I want to use the same bundle to handle them with two entity managers.

Comment: You could take a look at the orm config options in: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html  It's possible that you could put car and country in the same bundle but different directories using the 'dir' parameter.  That of course assumes that car and country have no relations with each other.