# Issues in entities from different bundles using different entity managers

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Edit:

I've prepared a tar.gz which once uncompressed and after running ./bin/vendors install fails to load the fixtures through php `scripts/createAll.php`. In the tar.gz there are 2 bundles using 2 different connections everyone with its own database.

I think Symfony2 fails to manage them properly. If you take a look at scripts/createAll.php will see how symfony fails to load both fixtures, but if you remove a random fixture (it doesn't matter Var_.php or Foo_.php everything runs fine, which seems to me that symfony is failing to manage entities correctly.)

LINK: http://www.2shared.com/file/2u4GhFVX/SymfonyTestCasetar.html

i want to tell `Symfony2` to use different `entity managers` for different `Bundle 
directories` so my config.yml looks like:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    default_entity_manager:   default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                myVendorURLCoreBundle: ~
                myVendormyBundleBundle: ~
                myVendormyBundleFooBundle:
                    prefix: "myVendor\myBundleFooBundle\Entity"
                    type: annotation
                    is_bundle: true
                    dir: "/Entity"
        formacions:
            connection: formacions
            mappings:
                myVendormyBundleFooBarBundle:
                    prefix: "myVendor\myBundleFooBarBundle\View"
                    type: annotation
                    is_bundle: false
                    dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/myVendor/myBundleFooBarBundle/View"
```

The problem is when using relationships between the entities in the different directories i get the following error caused by `vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php at line 142`

> Class FRJPC\SalleUrlFormacionsBundle\Entity\EspecialitatContingut is
>   not a valid entity or mapped super class

The probem is that sometimes "\" before the vendor name breaks the namespace. It's really strange.

Here is how i i link entities between each other:

```
namespace myVendor\myBundleFooBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity( repositoryClass="myVendor\myBundleFooBundle\Repository\ARepository" )
 * @ORM\ChangeTrackingPolicy( "DEFERRED_EXPLICIT" )
 * @ORM\Table( name="a" )
 */
class A
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column( type="integer", length="4" )
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue( strategy="AUTO" )
     */
    private $id;

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne( targetEntity="\myVendor\myBundleFooBarBundle\Entity\B", inversedBy="a", cascade={"persist"} )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn( name="FooBar", nullable=true, referencedColumnName="FooBar", onDelete="CASCADE" )
     */
    private $fooBar;
}
```

Second entity:

```
namespace myVendor\myBundleFooBarBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity( repositoryClass="myVendor\myBundleFooBarBundle\Repository\ARepository" )
 * @ORM\ChangeTrackingPolicy( "DEFERRED_EXPLICIT" )
 * @ORM\Table( name="a" )
 */
class B
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column( type="integer", length="4" )
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue( strategy="AUTO" )
     */
    private $id;

        /** @ORM\OneToMany( targetEntity="\myVendor\myBundleFooBundle\Entity\EspecialitatContingut", mappedBy="fooBar" ) */
        private $a;
}
```

Does any  one  has  a  clue  on  how should  i  link  each entity ?

**PD: Both entities work like  charm when they're in the same bundle and same directory.**

Answer (score 3):

All these Foos and Bars combined with an error message with a real name make it a bit difficult to follow and leaves open the possibility that posted code really doesn't match the actual code.  The FooBarBundle/View seems to be an unlikely place to store entities.

In any event a given entity manager such as formacions needs to be able to see all the relevant entities including those involved in relations.  It looks like you defined A in the foo bundle and B in the bar bundle and they both cross reference each other?

From your config, I don't see how the formacion em can see your A entity and likewise I don't see how the default em can see the B entity.  The fully qualified class name in the relation is not enough to share the entity doctrine metadata.  Hence the error messages.

I'd would actually be glad to be proven wrong about this.  It's a bit frustrating not to be able to do these sorts of things.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. As i understand, in confyg.yml i define different entity managers which are used by different bundles and those only know about each other when using FQDN in the relationships, is that concept wrong? I'm going to upload a test case example, so if you have the time, you can give it a look. Thanks a lot for your time, i'm really dsperate on how to solve this issue.

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9311485/1146363 The command: app/console doctrine:mapping:info --em EntityManagerName can give you some insight as to exactly what a given entity manager can see.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I did knew about the pp/console doctrine:mapping:info --em='foo' command but don't know how it can help. I think symfony have some kind of problem managing multiple connections as entities are fine, fixtures also and they can be loaded without problem when just one fixture exists.