# How to dynamically select EntityManager for use with ManyToMany on Symfony2 Form

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have a Symfony2 bundle where I am utilizing a dynamic selection of EntityManagers based on the subdomain in addition to a fixed EM for general settings, etc. For example, a user lands on `dev.mydomain.com` and is presented with a login screen that pulls information from a `default` database containing site title, colors, etc. The login script, however, references the `dev` database which contains the users and data for that subdomain. Similarly, when logging into `other.mydomain.com`, the login references the `other` database. This all works great and users are validated against their appropriate databases.

The issue I'm encountering is when I create a "new user form" using Symfony's Form system. I utilize a Many to Many relationship for user roles as outlined by The Book, but can't find a way to specify which EntityManager is used, causing it to look for the relationships against the `default` EntityManager.

Controller/UserController.php

```
public function addAction(Request $request) {

    $us = new User();

    // ORM Connection name stored in session from the login screen
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(
        $request->getSession()->get('database')
    );

    $form = $this->createForm(
        new UserType($em), $us
    );

    return $this->render(
        'MyBundle:User:create.html.twig',
        array( 'form' => $form->createView() )
    );
}
```

Entity/User.php

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $roles;
```

config.yml

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   "%database_driver%"
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
        dev:
            driver:   "%dev.database_driver%"
            host:     "%dev.database_host%"
            port:     "%dev.database_port%"
            dbname:   "%dev.database_name%"
            user:     "%dev.database_user%"
            password: "%dev.database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
orm:
  default_entity_manager: default
  auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
  entity_managers:
    default:
        connection: default
        mappings:
            MyBundle: ~
    dev:
        connection: dev
        mappings:
            MyBundle: ~
```

*Is there a way to pass a specified EntityManager into createForm or FormBuilder to be utilized by the built-in ManyToMany ORM annotation?* To be clear, the rest of the form works appropriately, adding the user to the desired EntityManager -- it's just the Roles field that's still referencing `default`.

Comment: Could you add the config file, where you defined the entity managers, please? And why did you not choose to have 2 ore more bundles instead of the one?

Comment: I've included it at the bottom of the question. I chose to have a single bundle because it is an application that utilizes the same code base across multiple institutions. I wanted an easy way to "spin up" a new institution simply by including them in the config and `default` database `site` table which includes the subdomain, logos, etc. while maintaining institution based permissions on their distinct databases.

Comment: At the moment you have two entity managers managing the same thing. So most likely if you run a `app/console doctrine:schema:validate` neither of the schemas are in sync, because from what I understand some entities are managed by one entity manager only(mapped in one database), while the others are managed by the other entity manager(mapped in some other database also). Write the distinctions in the config and I think it should work. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311485/working-with-two-entity-managers-in-the-same-bundle-in-symfony2

Comment: @anegrea thanks for the response. Running the statement results in the following, implying that everything is good to go in the schemas.  I've also updated the question to include the distinctions, with them pulling parameters from another file. Multiple entities work all across the site, just not for this one field on the form.

`php app/console doctrine:schema:validate
[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FormBuilder utilized inside of the Form/UserType.php file has `add()` methods, allowing one to add the components of the entity. The `add()` method can take an array of options as the third element. One of these options is `em`:

```
->add('roles', 'entity', array(
         'class'=>'MyBundle:Role',
         'property'=>'name',
         'em'=>$options['em'],
         'multiple'=>true
      ))
```

I was able to pass the dynamically determined entity manager into the file through the `createForm()` method inside of Controller/User.php to be accessed from the above options array:

```
$form = $this->createForm(
           new UserType($em), $us, array('em'=>$em)
        );
```

Lastly, I ensured that the entity manager was required by including it in `setDefaultOptions()` in Form/UserType.php:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setRequired(array('em'));

    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'em' => null
    ));
}
```

In doing this, the ManyToMany Roles field inside my form pulls from and persists to the correct entity manager.