# Use symfony2 application with mysql & postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, symfony, doctrine, schema

I develop an application with symfony2 framework.
The application need to work on differents servers, one with mysql and one with postgresql.

For postgresql, I need to use schema="admin" in several tables. So I have make on entities :

> @ORM\Table(schema="admin",name="si_user")

It's works fine on postgresql.

When I try to update or create schema sql, doctrine don't create or find the table. And it's work find when I delete schema="admin".

> @ORM\Table(name="si_user")

Have you any solutions to keep schema attribut and mysql don't use schema attribut?

Thanks you for help.

Comment: "*When I try to update or create schema sql, doctrine don't create or find the table.*"—do you mean that Doctrine can't create/find the table on MySQL, when defined with `schema="admin"`?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Use two connections and two entity managers and there will be no conflict among annotations http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1: same entity class, multiple mappings

First, as pointed out by @Jekis, you will need different connections and entity managers.

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
            postgres:
                driver:   pdo_pgsql
                host:     "%pg_host%"
                port:     "%pg_port%"
                dbname:   "%pg_name%"
                user:     "%pg_user%"
                password: "%pg_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:
                        type: yml
                        dir: Resources/config/doctrine/default
            postgres:
                connection: postgres
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:
                        type: yml
                        dir: Resources/config/doctrine/postgres
```

Second, since you need different mapping information for each connection on the same entities, my guess is you are going to need something else than annotations for you metadata.
Like yml, for example.
That way, you can define a specific mapping for each entity manager.

MySQL:

```
# Resources/config/doctrine/default/User.orm.yml
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: user
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Postgres:

```
# Resources/config/doctrine/postgres/User.orm.yml
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    schema: admin
    table: user
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Then, when calling you `doctrine:schema:update` command, you can also pass the entity manager for the database you want to update.

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:create
php bin/console doctrine:schema:create -em postgres
```

Here's the test I made:
https://github.com/vtoulouse/multiple-mapping-test

## Solution 2: multiple entity classes

Alternatively, if you want to use annotations, you will have to duplicate your entity classes, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15027134/5845942).