# Is it possible to use two diffrent document managers with different databases for the same bundle in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm, doctrine-mongodb

My goal is to have two different document managers connected to different databases that share the same database models.

I have heavily changed my database model and I would like to write a custom migration script that retrieves objects from the old model reads its values and then creates a new object on the new schema with the information of the old object.

I have found a related stackoverflow question here: 
[Working with two entity managers in the same bundle in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311485/working-with-two-entity-managers-in-the-same-bundle-in-symfony2)

Howewer, this solution suggests to use different prefixes for each database and it stores the classes for the data model in different folders:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection:   default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   %database_driver%
            host:     %database_host%
            port:     %database_port%
            dbname:   %database_name%
            user:     %database_user%
            password: %database_password%
            charset:  UTF8
        second:
            driver:   %database_sqlite_driver%
            host:     ~
            port:     ~
            dbname:   %database_sqlite_shop_name%
            path:     %database_sqlite_shop_name%
            user:     ~
            password: ~
            charset:  UTF8

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    default_entity_manager:   default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection:       default
            mappings:
                YourBundle:
                  # you must specify the type
                  type:     "annotation"    
                  # The directory for entity (relative to bundle path)
                  dir:      "Entity/FirstDb"        
                  #the prefix 
                  prefix:   "Your\Bundle\Entity\FirstDb" 
        shop:
            connection:       second
            mappings:
                YourBundle:
                  type: "annotation"
                  #here the second path where entity for the connection stand
                  dir: "Entity/SecondDb" 
                  #the prefix
                  prefix: "Your\Bundle\Entity\SecondDb"
```

I would really just like to have two different document manager objects that share the same models in the same folder but are connected to diffrent databases. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you get any error when you try mapping same documents to both `DocumentManager`s?

Comment: Yes the document manager does not retrieve any documents any more. I get none for every document that I query for. I assume that this could be related to some conflict that this configuration creates.

Comment: Try to modify these. For mongo: [Using multiple mongodb document manager and connections in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/fukm/using-multiple-mongodb-document-managers-and-connections-in-symfony) and For MySQL: [Using multiple MySQL entity managers for multiple bundles and databases](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/7cpx/using-multiple-mysql-entity-managers-for-multiple-bundles-and-databases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it is indeed possible to be connected to different databases in the same Symfony Bundle. This answer led me to a possible solution: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15110867/2174832

```
#services.yml
acme_app.dynamic_connection:
class: %acme.dynamic_doctrine_connection.class%
calls:
    - [setDoctrineConnection, @doctrine.dbal.default_connection]]


<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\AppBundle;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\ServiceUnavailableHttpException;
use Exception;

class DynamicDoctrineConnection
{
    /**
     * @var Connection
     */
    private $connection;

    /**
     * Sets the DB Name prefix to use when selecting the database to connect to
     *
     * @param  Connection       $connection
     * @return SiteDbConnection $this
     */
    public function setDoctrineConnection(Connection $connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;

        return $this;
    }

    public function setUpAppConnection()
    {
        if ($this->request->attributes->has('appId')) {
            $connection = $this->connection;
            $params     = $this->connection->getParams();

            // we also check if the current connection needs to be closed based on various things
            // have left that part in for information here
            // $appId changed from that in the connection?
            // if ($connection->isConnected()) {
            //     $connection->close();
            // }

            // Set default DB connection using appId
            //$params['host']   = $someHost;
            $params['dbname'] = 'Acme_App'.$this->request->attributes->get('appId');

            // Set up the parameters for the parent
            $connection->__construct(
                $params, $connection->getDriver(), $connection->getConfiguration(),
                $connection->getEventManager()
            );

            try {
                $connection->connect();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // log and handle exception
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

With the solution above one can write a service that can be called to change the database that the current entity manager is connected to to a different database.

Unfortunately the **solution above only works for the PDO driver (Mysql).** 
Since our technology stack includes mongodb and we use the **doctrine-mongodb bundle** I had to look for a **differnt solution**.

The doctrine-mongodb documentation has a section about setting up a custom document manager here: 
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/introduction.html

I was unable to get the right doctrine-mongodb odm document mappings to work with the instructions in the doc and therefore the only solution for me was to create a simple PHP mongoclient connection:

```
$mongo = new \Mongo('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$legacyDbDocumentMangager = $mongo->selectDB('backed_up_prod_db');
$legacyUserCollection = $legacyDbDocumentMangager->selectCollection('User');
$user = $legacyUserCollection->findOne(array('email' => 'matyas@stackoverflow.com'));
```

The only differnce between this simple php mongodb driver and the doctrine-mongodb odm is that the results of the queries of this driver are associative arrays and the results of the doctrine-mongodb odm diver are objects.

I hope this information is useful to someone.