# Symfony 2.8 - Doctrine schema force only selected entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm currently in a situation where I have two databases (one MySQL and SQLite database). I'm using the SQLite database only for two log entities which I need to keep separate from the main (MySQL) database. Is there any possibility to update the SQLite database only with those two entities and leave the MySQL database untouched? I can't find any command for that.

However, I found the following options:

1. Use doctrine schema update force on both the SQLite and MySQL database. The downside of this solution is that I pollute the SQLite with the rest of the schema and the MySQL database with the two log entities.
2. Put the two log entities into a separate bundle so that I can call schema update only on a particular bundle.

Although these solutions solve the problem, they aren't really optimal. **Is there any possibility to update only certain entities for a certain entity manager?**

Comment: How about `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --help` => `--em[=EM]            The entity manager to use for this command` ? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311485/working-with-two-entity-managers-in-the-same-bundle-in-symfony2) might be of use aswell.

Comment: An entity manager is used to make a connection with a certain database, right? I want to only update specific entities within an entity manager.

Comment: See the edited link, basically - you configure which entity uses which manager in the `config.yml`.

Comment: I don't see how this solves my problem. In the documentation of Symfony (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-entities-outside-of-a-bundle) it seems like that I can change the Doctrine config files and entity folder for a particular connection, not a connection per entity.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this after declaring two entitymanager in your config

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: <your_mysql_em>
    entity_managers:
        mysql_em:
            connection: <mysql_connection_name>
            mappings:
                AppBundle:
                    type: 'annotation'
                    dir: 'Entity/'
         logger_em:
            connection: <sqlite_connection_name>
            mappings:
               AppBundle:
                    type: 'annotation'
                    dir: 'Logger/Entity'
```

After you can choose a em to update your schema:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --em logger_em
```

see documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html